# The use of HTTP status to communicate application circumstances

Tags: restlet, http-error

Suppose I ask a question to an criminal register: http://server/demographics/party/{partyId} and that person is not known on that system.
Is that an error? Isn't it a good thing?

When returning 404, it is an error code, Restlet has implemented it as a specific URL cannot be resolved to a route to a server-resource (a handling class), an erroneous situation.

In my opinion, if a system understands a call, and is able to process it without errors, it should return 200 (HTTP-ok), and it should return the information: "We don't know this person".

What is the best thing to do?

Comment: This is an opinion loaded topic. Some people are REST fans for example and will insist on a 404... Put this question on Programmers.

Comment: Do they provide a different URL that is a search operation? *"and is able to process it without errors"* - But there *was* an error, at least from a certain point of view, that you requested something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* in returning a 404 status code. It simply means "you asked for a resource, and it doesn't exist". If it did return 200, it would have to somehow return an additional status code telling you that everything went fine, but the resource couldn't be found. That's unnecessary, because 404 already means exactly that.

A status 500 is normally returned to mean "something went wrong, I can't tell you if the resource exists or not". Now if you returned a 404 to mean that, this would be a mistake.

Whether it's a good thing or not is not doesn't have anything to do with HTTP or REST. And BTW, if the register was a file containing the survivors of a disaster, you would probably find it bad to not find the person you looked for, unless maybe if the person is your mother in law, unless you actually love your mother in law. (this is meant as a joke, for those who don't find it obvious).

Comment: 404 can also mean that the URL you provide could not be routed by Restlet. So a client has no useful information from the 404. It has to take further steps, same as it would have to do when the response is 200.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from returning a message, or even a structured JSON body, in addition to the 404 status code. I guess Restlet already returns a message indicating the reason for the 404.

Answer (score 0):

A web service could be implemented in a way that produces either kind of response.

If it is being implemented in a way that is truer to HTTP/Rest, then '404 not found' would be the appropriate response for not finding something.  This is what the 404 status is for.

It may help to think of your request as saying 'I assume this record exists, and I want to see it', and the 404 response as saying 'You are in error that record does not exist'.

If this URL is going to be used by code (rather than be displayed in a browser), then if you don't make a distinction in the response status then you will have to add extra information to the response body to make the difference obvious.

If this URL is going to be displayed to a user in a browser, then the server is still able to display content in the response body for a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Please read: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/restful_error_handling.html#__federated=1

Quoting:

Conclusion:

- Human Readable Error Messages: Part of the major appeal of REST based web services is that you can open any browser, type in the right URL, and see an immediate response -- no special tools needed. However, HTTP error codes do not always provide enough information. For example, if we take option 1 above, and request and invalid book ID, we get back a 404 Error Code. From the developer perspective, have we actually typed in the wrong host name, or an invalid book ID? It's not immediately clear. In Option 3 (DAS), we get back a blank page with no information. To view the actual error code, you need to run a network sniffer, or point your browser through a proxy. For all these reasons, I think Option 4 has a lot to offer. It significantly lowers the barrier for new developers, and enables all information related to a web service to be directly viewable within a web browser.
- Application Specific Errors: Option 1 has the disadvantage of not being directly viewable within a browser. It also has the additional disadvantage of mapping all HTTP error codes to application specific error codes. HTTP status codes are specific to document retrieval and posting, and these may not map directly to your application domain. For example, one of the DAS error codes relates to invalid genomic coordinates (sequence coordinate is out of bounds/invalid). What HTTP error code would we map to in this case?
- Machine Readable Error Codes: As a third criteria, error codes should be easily readable by other applications. For example, the XooMLe application returns back only human readable error messages, e.g. "Invalid Google API key supplied". An application parsing a XooMLe response would have to search for this specific error message, and this can be notoriously brittle -- for example, the XooMLe server might simply change the message to "Invalid Key Supplied". Error codes, such as those provided by DAS are important for programmatic control, and easy creation of exceptions. For example, if XooMLe returned a 1001 error code, a client application could do a quick lookup and immediately throw an InvalidKeyException.

Based on these three criteria, here's my vote for best error handling option:

- Use HTTP Status Codes for problems specifically related to HTTP, and not specifically related to your web service.
- When an error occurs, always return an XML document detailing the error.
- Make sure the XML error document contains both an error code, and a human readable error message. For example:


  1001
  Invalid Google API key supplied

By following these three simple practices, you can make it significantly easier for others to interface with your service, and react when things go wrong. New developers can easily see valid and invalid requests via a simple web browser, and programs can easily (and more robustly) extract error codes and act appropriately.
The Amazon.com web services API follows the approach of returned XML document can specify an ErrorMsg element.
XooMLe also follows this approach. (XooMLe provides a RESTful API wrapper to the existing SOAP based Google API).
Another approach is by DAS ( Distributed Annotation System) which always returns 200 if there was no HTTP-error and has error information in the HTTP-header, which is less favorable, because it is not human readable, as a browser does not display the HTTP-header.